# Microphone not working with Steelseries 5HV2 Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, skype, 32-bit, microphone, headset

I have recently updated my Packard Bell Easynote LM-81 to Ubuntu 12.10 32-Bit.

I tried to start a Skype conversation (installed from the software center, without problems), when I found that my microphone in the headset isn't taking in the sound.

The internal microphone in my computer worked fine though. I looked in sound settings, and from there I could see that it said "Microphone, Built in Audio" if the microphone cable was plugged in, and it not, it said: "Internal Microphone, Built in Audio". I have tried finding somewhere to download some software for the headset, but it didn't seem to work. I'm not a Ubuntu nerd, since I recently installed, so does anyone know what it might be?

---

The microphone worked fine when I was running Windows 7.

Comment: This is most likely a driverissue. Which headset is this?

Comment: Running `$ sudo lshw -html > your-file-name.html` will post systeminformation to a html file in.

Comment: product: SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)

Comment: Try running `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec`

Comment: Codec: Realtek ALC272X

Comment: I would just like to say, that I rebooted my computer and headset, and now it works perfectly fine. I never realized that rebooting still is the best way to repair your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Community has an excellent guide to fixing problems with the Intel HDA.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto